# Nginx proxy for vue and fastapi

Tags: vue.js, nginx, fastapi

I am trying to deploy my app with vue.js as frontend and fastapi as backend. But I am having issue when deploy the app on the cloud. I have nginx configure like below.

I am binding backend to port 8080 and frontend to 8000. But with this configuration, I can only see my frontend page. The backend api is not respond. Can anyone show me how to fix it?

```
server {
  listen      80;
  server_name example.com;
  charset utf-8;
  root    vis/dist;
  index   index.html index.htm;


location /api/ {
  proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
}
location  / {
  proxy_pass  http://localhost:8080;
  proxy_set_header    Host                $host;
  proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Host    $host;
  proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Server  $host;
  proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto   $scheme;
  proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $remote_addr;
  proxy_redirect off;
  proxy_connect_timeout 90s;
  proxy_read_timeout 90s;
  proxy_send_timeout 90s;
}

error_log  /var/log/nginx/vue-app-error.log;
access_log /var/log/nginx/vue-app-access.log;
}
```

Comment: Generally there is no need to proxy pass a vue app to your local host- you just serve the static files from the build process directly in your nginx config. Most of the proxy headers also seem relevant for the API endpoint and not the vue endpoint. Does the api work if you switch the ports around? (i.e. is it a firewall issue in relation to exposed ports on localhost)

Comment: So I should remove frontend proxy and add static files from building? Currently the api proxy is not working. The frontend page is working though.